# how to make an ajax call with jquery loaded in the body section not head section

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a layout file where i included Jquery just before closing tag.

```
//layout.handlebars
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head></head>
   <body>
    {{{body}}} // renders the body content
    <script src='/js/jquery-2.2.4.min.js'></script>    
   </body>
</html>
```

I also have a page specific javascript(helper.js) that makes an Ajax  call.

```
<div>Some sample data</div>
<script src="/js/helper.js"></script>
```

but the problem here is jquery is loaded at the end of the page but i am referring to it in the external javascript before jquery is loaded. which shows me '$' is not defined and i know that is obvious.

One solution to this will be like adding jquery to the head section but that is not what i want.

Is there any approach that i can apply to make an ajax call from external file without moving Jquery to head section.

Any help is much appreciated!!

Comment: write your helper.js script after your jquery library

Comment: well then u have to add jquery on that page(helper.js) too.......or load jquery in the helper.js only because it is loaded first.

Comment: I'm not sure this will work, but you can try this dirty solution. You can wrap you `helper.js` code in `window.onload = function() { //helper.js code }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any approach that i can apply to make an ajax call from external file without moving Jquery to head section.

Yes, I assume you already understand the cause of the issue. As you see below the final content is ..

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head></head>
   <body>
    <div>Some sample data</div>
    <script src="/js/helper.js"></script>  <!--Jquery is not loaded yet, and hence $ is undefined -->
    <script src='/js/jquery-2.2.4.min.js'></script>    
   </body>
</html>
```

As you already know one option is to move `jquery` anywhere in the HTML but make sure its loaded before any other jquery dependent files. Now since you don't want to take this option. we have another option.

**Solution:**
Our only aim is to make sure the `jquery` library is loaded prior to any other jquery dependent files.

We can get the files on `document.ready` using **[$.getScript()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/)**

```
$(function(){
 $.getScript( "/js/helper.js", function( data, textStatus, jqxhr ) {      
  console.log( "Load was performed." );
 });
});
```

---

**Extras:** If you feel this is a overhead and you cannot add this code to all the files in your page (since there can be too many files ), You can write a generic function and a global array variable , This function will check for file paths in the array and execute each one synchronously and remove from the array. Make sure this generic function is called in every `document.ready` event.

Comment: I was thinking of this approach.it seems good to me,Is there  any other approach we can use here?

Comment: @SarojSasmal other I can think of is `$('head').append('<script src="/js/helper.js"></script>')` with in `document ready`. Which give you the same result.

Answer (score 0):

One Solution is that You can put the jquery script at the start of body tag before {{{body}}} section .. In this way your helper script will be rendered after jquery and your problem will be solved .....

Comment: `One solution to this will be like adding jquery to the head section but that is not what i want.` this is what OP says

Answer (score 0):

Well its not pretty but you could use some kind of test and wait loop something like

```
<script>
(function test(){
  if(  window.jQuery ){
    //your jQuery code
  } else {
    setTimeout(function(){ test(); }, 200);
  }
})
</script>
```